# What is the difference between Parse, Execute and Fetch?

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, database-performance, sqlperformance

The tkprof utility generates the trace file with three types of information which are Parse, Execute and Fetch. Could you please explain what is the difference between these three? What will be counted as Parse and Execute and Fetch?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

When you issue a SQL statement, Oracle:

1. Parses your SQL statement. That means Oracle analyzes the correctness of the syntax, checks the access rights, and creates the execution plan (or takes it from the cache).
2. Actually executes your SQL statement.
3. For SELECT statements, Oracle fetches the rows returned by your query. (For INSERT, DELETE, and UPDATE Oracle fetches nothing).

The numbers of these operations is written in the trace.

If we are talking about the performance tuning, the idea is to parse SQL statements once and then keep them in cache, execute them when you need and do not close cursors if you will need them again to reduce number of fetches.